# Codeigniter Composer Phpmailer

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, phpmailer

I'm struggling with Codeigniter + PHPMailer via Composer.
I'm getting this error:

```
Class 'PHPMailer' not found
```

I have CI version 3.1.5 and I've composed PHPMailer 6.0.0 using the following command:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

Inside my root folder, so it created something like this:

```
/CI_root
 |-- application
 |-- system
 |-- vendor
 |   |-- phpmailer
 |       |-- phpmailer
 |           |-- language
 |           |-- src
 |-- composer.json
```

Inside my application/config/config.php there is this line

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = FCPATH."vendor/autoload.php";
```

PS.: I tried changing to `$config['composer_autoload'] = "./vendor/autoload.php";` as well

And finally, the root composer.json

```
{
"description": "The CodeIgniter framework",
"name": "codeigniter/framework",
"type": "project",
"homepage": "https://codeigniter.com",
"license": "MIT",
"support": {
    "forum": "http://forum.codeigniter.com/",
    "wiki": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/codeigniter",
    "source": "https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter"
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.7",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1"
},
"suggest": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "Provides better randomness in PHP 5.x"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mikey179/vfsStream": "1.1.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
}
```

}

And inside the controller

```
public function index()
{
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    // other of stuff
```

Funny thing is mpdf loads okay. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The line `"php": ">=5.3.7"` should be updated to require PHP 5.5 if you're using PHPMailer 6.0.

Comment: I'm running on PHP 7.0 anyway, but I gonna change that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composer auto-loading should just be TRUE:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

This is because CodeIgniter already knows that your composer autoloaded files will be in `/application/vendor`

at the top of your file where you want to use PHP mailer, probably need something like:

```
use PHPMailer;
```

Actually, in the PHPMailer docs, they show:

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Comment: But then CI looks at application folder, It also accepts a folder, that's why I can load mPDF just fine. The problem is somehow with phpmailer I believe.

Comment: I updated answer. Are you using `use PHPMailer;` at the top of your file where you're trying to use it?

Comment: Had to update my answer again based on info at: https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: Right - can't do without that namespace!

Comment: Also, you are showing that your vendor directory is right inside the application directory, so you can use TRUE. If mPDF is not in there, maybe mPDF should be? I don't see how you can autoload both locations.

Comment: I tried both suggestions inside my index function, but I got syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE). Or should it go somewhere else?

Comment: It needs to go at the very top of the file, before the class is opened.

Comment: Maybe my drawing is not very representative, but vendor is outside application, is supposed to be the same level, inside root

Comment: That's Ok, you still need to use "use". Even the examples of PHPMailer will show that.

Comment: Okay, now it got instantiated! Thanks folks! You're awesome!

Comment: From point of security it's better to be in application directory than in publicly accessible directory.

Comment: @BrianGottier, sir if you don't mind can you tell me where i supposed to put this line `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
`  inside `function` or `top of the script`

Comment: @EaB I always put them at the top of the script, right after the namespace declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I just add at the top, before class

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Then inside the controller method,

simply use it as always:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```